# How to make CLI enter new line automatically

Tags: cisco, router, cli

I would like to know the command to configure CLI on cisco equipment to make the cursor move to the new line right away after it showed the message. 
**So for example:**

```
Router#
Router#
*00:00:00: Interface Ethernet0 chaged state to up.Link blablalba* ***(cursor is here)****
```

and then the cursor stays on the same line where the message was displayed..

I want it to move to the next line right away automatically.

**Example:**

```
Router#
Router#
00:00:00: Interface Ethernet0 chaged state to up. Line protocol blablalba
Router#****(cursor is here)****
```

Comment: `logging synchronous` is what you want, as @KellerG and @Ryan have mentioned, but typically having logging sent to the console is undesirable, unless you're doing debugging.

Comment: Ctrl-r  is worth mentioning  to refresh the CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for "logging synchronous".

Answer (score 14):

Specifically, you're looking for this:

```
line con 0
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 15
 logging synchronous
```